# How to filter cars by key-value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I implement car auction, and I have a car items list inside the catalog component. I have buttons that specify the type of car (suv, bike, passenger..)
[image]

when I click on any of the buttons, I want to redirect to catalog with a filtered list of cars with according typeCar.
So data with objects is in App.js
I have a Catalog component inside App.js
The catalog component has a list of CarItems (CarItem is a child in Catalog that receives props and shows info about every car (I used the map to show the whole list).
The problem that the catalog is not filtered.
I declared Route in App.js.

```
 <Route
        exact
        path="/catalog/typeCar"
        render={({ match }) => (
          <Catalog item={data.find((item) => String(item.typeCar) === String(match.params.typeCar))} />
        )}
```

buttons are in another component, and I created links for each:

```
      <Link  to={`/catalog/passanger`}><img src={img_4} className='white-fill mr-2' width='70px'/></Link> 
            
      <Link  to={`/catalog/bike`}> <img src={img_1} width='70px' className='white-fill mr-2' /></Link>

      <Link  to={`/catalog/suv`}> <img src={img_2} width='70px' className='white-fill' /></Link>

      <Link  to={`/catalog/bus`}> <img src={img_3} width='70px' className='white-fill ml-2' /></Link>

 </Col>
```

So I click on a button and see URL is changed: `http://localhost:3000/catalog/passanger`
, but there is no info on the page. it's not redirecting to the Catalog page (component) with a list of CarItems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrectly defined your routes with [URL params](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params). You need to use `:typeCar`:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/catalog/:typeCar" // Here
  render={({ match }) => (
    <Catalog
      item={data.find(
        (item) => String(item.typeCar) === String(match.params.typeCar)
      )}
    />
  )}
/>
```

After this when you go to a route like `/catalog/bike` using `Link` or `history.push`, the value of [match.params.typeCar](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match) (in Route's match object) will be `bike`.

Comment: Catalog has child <CarItem data={data} /> components. Data is array of car objects. and this data is undefined once I click Suv img or any other type of cars I'm looking for. So url is changed but it shows err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: should I pass to Catalog and then to CarItem ?

Comment: I map through data arr in CarItem component to render a list of cars in Catalog

Comment: You are saying that `Catalog` has a child `CartItem` which needs access to full `data` array? In that case you need to pass full data only: `<Catalog data={data} />` and do the filter **inside** `Catalog` component using `props.match.params.typeCar`

Comment: Also, use this at Route - `<Route exact path="/catalog/:typeCar" render={(props) => ( <Catalog {...props} data={data} />)}/>`. Now child `CarItem` can have access to full `data` array.

Comment: better now it goes to catalog page with endpoint of car type but output is all the cars (the whole list) despite the endpoint is different

Comment: You need to do `filter` or `find` like you were doing at Route level, but now inside `Catalog` component. That also means that in `Catalog` component, you need both *fulldata* and filtered data.

Comment: Still working on it:
have several issues:
i Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in CarItem despite I pass {data, filteredData} as props

Comment: You can share your repo with me if there are too many issues, and you need help in fixing those.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-tdd-2q9br?file=/src/App.js:1667-1675

Comment: I put main issues into codesandbox
the first details page is not working here, but working in my project, IDK why

Comment: the second that I've mentioned on this post.
I have Header where I have several car Types and I wanna filter that cars in catalog by object key value:   typeCar: "passenger" or whatever I click on

Comment: Also I need to show cars on auction different from catalog . I mean on  catalog cars with property -  typeSale: "auction" should render and catalog should include just cars with  typeSale: "buy now"

Comment: plus I need to implement filter method in Filter component to show according cars in catalog and auction (depends where filter is implemented). Filter is in both auction and catalog components. I used 'react-select' library for this task.

Comment: Thank you Ajeet !! as always works from the first fix:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Array.filter method:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/catalog/typeCar"
  render={({ match }) => (
    <Catalog item={ data.filter((v) => String(v.typeCar) === String(match.params.typeCar)) } />
  )}/>
```